# How to set compatiblity view in ie7?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, internet-explorer-7

When I am navigating to one of the page in my application, The `Compatibility View` of IE changes to `Quirks Mode`.

In IE8 and IE9, I overcome this problem by using this code, however, it's not working for IE7

```
if($ie_version =='7') { 
      echo $ie_version; ?>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible: IE=7" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
<?php }
else if($ie_version =='9'){ ?>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"  value="9" > 
<?php }
else if($ie_version =='8') { ?>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" value="8" > 
<?php }   ?>
```

Can some one suggest the remedy? Also, I want to know why the mode changes to quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Goto **tools->Compatibility view settings**

And see if you have any sites defined in there. If they are in there, then it will change to compatibility view for those sites only.

Remove them if you dont want them there

Comment: I want to dod that in coding boss

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a html error a comment line is used before the actual html starts , I just removed it now it works fine